# Changing Apple ID on second hand Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, restore

I bought a Macbook Pro second hand and the previous owner did not disable their iCloud account. Is there any way to erase it back to factory settings so I can set up my iCloud account on the device?

Answer (score 1):

Can you go back to the seller? I'd try to contact them and have them remove it. Or contact the original owner.

Also check and see if its firmware locked.